# Configuring routing for network faults simulator

Tags: windows, routing, nat

I'm trying to configure routing on my test machine to pass all traffic via the network errors simulator (WANem).
WANem runs in a virtual machine, in the same network with internet gateway. It has NAT enabled (`nat add eth0`). The test machine (the client) is using Windows. On the test machine I'm executing this:

```
route /f
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <WANem_IP> -p
```

Than I run `tracert` to check that traffic goes via WANem, and everything seems ok. However, after making a few test on the test machine I see that `tracert` doesn't show  as the first hop. And `route print` shows that route via real internet gateway (192.168.1.1 in my case) is added, which was not present before.
So, traffic bypasses my WANem gateway. Any ideas why this happens, and how to avoid this?

UPD my routes after I've finished my setup

```
===========================================================================                                      
Active Routes:                                                                                                   
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric                                      
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.82    192.168.1.61       1                                      
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1                                      
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.61    192.168.1.61       10                                     
     192.168.1.61  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10                                     
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.61    192.168.1.61       10                                     
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.1.61    192.168.1.61       10                                     
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.61    192.168.1.61       1                                      
Default Gateway:      192.168.1.82                                                                               
===========================================================================                                      
Persistent Routes:                                                                                               
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric                                                      
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.68       1
```

Comment: Could you post the output of 1route print`? Do you have a default gateway set on any NICs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to disable ICMP Redirect as described here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverPN/thread/c2443864-e097-4576-bc72-6de0b7028fee